# The content of my text file is not showing when I run the program

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read the contents of a text file and print them. I cannot figure out why the content is not displayed when I run the program.
This is my code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadTxtfile{

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Open the file
    File file = new File("chessfile.txt");

    //Open files for reading
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    while(!file.exists()){
      System.out.println("The file chessfile.txt is not found.");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    //Read lines from the file
    while(inputFile.hasNext());

    //Read next
    String piece = inputFile.nextLine();
    String color = inputFile.nextLine();
    String column = inputFile.nextLine();
    String row = inputFile.nextLine();

    //Display File
    System.out.printf(piece, color, column, row);

    //Close file
    inputFile.close();
  }

}//End of main
```

Comment: What is the output? Is the file found?

Comment: `while(inputFile.hasNext());` ???? i.e. Busy loop doing nothing while there is data available...

Comment: the program loops indefinitely at while loop

Comment: The output should be this: Pawn white B 2 
Queen white D 1 
Rook white A 1 
Knight white B 1 
Bishop white C 1 
King white E 1

Comment: I'm trying to read the txt file to use it as an input and then storage it on  a 2d array (8x8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things first you dont want to loop while the file exists and then use system.exit if you really need to just use an if statement

```
if(!file.exists()){
   System.out.println("The file chessfile.txt is not found.");
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Second your going to want to use file.hasNextLine() instead of hasNext and also where are the curly braces for your loop this is what it should look like.

```
   while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
       String piece = inputFile.nextLine();
       String color = inputFile.nextLine();
       String column = inputFile.nextLine();
       String row = inputFile.nextLine();
   }
```

Finnnaly i guess with printf your trying to display them neatly well you cant do that outside of the loop so instead of doing all that nonsense create a String array and store each of the lines in that as you get the different values. Assuming that your data is on seperate lines it should look somewhat like this.

```
     ArrayList<String> peices = new ArrayList<String>();

     while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
         String peice = "";
         peice += inputFile.nextLine() + " ";
         peice += inputFile.nextLine() + " ";
         peice += inputFile.nextLine() + " ";
         peice += inputFile.nextLine() + " ";
         peices.add(peice);
     }
```

And finnaly to display them on multiple lines you should use a simple enhanced loop.

```
for(String i : peices) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your while loop is not working. so next line data not coming in a string object.
and if you want getting all your text file data in one line try below loop.

```
String line ="";
      while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        line += scanner.nextLine();

      System.out.printf(line );
```